# the android emulator does not start, avd

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, emulation, android-virtual-device

this is my situation: I have a XPS under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64-bit

I downloaded the latest Android SDK with eclipse. The SDK works fine, but when I create a new AVD and I run. My AVD loads but not displayed.
I do not understand, do you have an idea about my problem ?

Thank's

I start my avd from command line :

```
romain@XPS-Dak:~/.android$ emulator -verbose -avd Test
emulator: found SDK root at /home/romain/android-sdk-linux
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 3
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 1024x600
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 1024x600
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/romain/.android/default.keyset
emulator: found SDK root at /home/romain/android-sdk-linux
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/romain/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/emulator/skins/dynamic//layout'
emulator: loaded dynamic skin width=1024 height=600 bpp=16

emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/romain/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-3/images//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/romain/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-3/images//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/romain/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-3/images//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = yes
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = no
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 1024
  hw.lcd.height = 600
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 16
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = /home/romain/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-3/images//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/romain/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-3/images//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/romain/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-3/images//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = Test
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/home/romain/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /home/romain/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-arm -android-hw /home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=/home/romain/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-3/images//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-romain/emulator-wbnmYS
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '16m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/romain/.android/avd/Test.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Comment: We'll need some more detail to help you... Please describe: "My AVD loads but not displayed." I'd like to see a screenshot of the emulator, add a link to the image once you post it on [Imgur](http://imgur.com).

Comment: Also, try running the emulator from the command line with the `-verbose` flag, to see what error messages you get.

Comment: I just add new item on the article

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You ran into the same problem that I did, outlined in [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34233). Find your `libOpenglRender.so` in your SDK `tools/` directory, and rename it to something else.

Comment: @RomainDaquin: "It's in Ubuntu only ?" -- if you read through the issue, you will see that other Linux distros are affected (e.g., Fedora).

Comment: For 64 bit remove the lib64OpenglRender.so file. Spent an hour debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution to the OP's exact problem, but to the "the android emulator does not start, avd" nevertheless.

Make sure there's nothing else competing for virtualization.

I had a headless Virtual Box image running and experienced similar behavior. It would show as started, but the emulator wasn't visible. The `./emulator -verbose -avd ...` would just never finish.

Answer (score -4):

You need to be patient during first run. It takes a while to load.