# My Android emulator cannot start. Error in load OpenGL lib

Tags: android, opengl, android-emulator

I met same problem here: [the android emulator does not start, avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463197/the-android-emulator-does-not-start-avd?rq=1)
I try do all solution in that post but emulator still not working.

- My OS: Windows 8.1 Preview 64bit
- GPU: ATI Radeon HD 7670M
- SDK Version: R22.01
- Emulator device: Emulator stopped working all.

Here is my logcat when run emulator with verbose log:

```
>emulator: found SDK root at F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk
>emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.ini
>emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd
>emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/config.ini
>emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
>emulator: Found AVD target API level: 10
>emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 480x800
>emulator: autoconfig: -skin 480x800
>emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
>emulator: keyset loaded from: C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\default.keyset
>emulator: found SDK root at F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk
>emulator: trying to load skin file 'F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/tools/lib/emulator/skins/dynamic//layout
'
>emulator: loaded dynamic skin width=480 height=800 bpp=16

>emulator: autoconfig: -kernel F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/system-images\android-10\x86\/kernel-qemu
>emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/system-images\android-10\x86\/ramdisk.img
>emulator: Using initial system image: F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/system->images\android-10\x86\/system.i
mg
>emulator: autoconfig: -data C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img
>emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userdata.img
>emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/cache.img
>emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

>Content of hardware configuration file:
>  hw.cpu.arch = x86
>  hw.ramSize = 512
>  hw.screen = touch
>  hw.mainKeys = yes
>  hw.trackBall = no
>  hw.keyboard = yes
>  hw.keyboard.lid = yes
>  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
>  hw.dPad = no
>  hw.gsmModem = yes
>  hw.gps = yes
>  hw.battery = no
>  hw.accelerometer = yes
>  hw.audioInput = yes
>  hw.audioOutput = yes
>  hw.sdCard = yes
>  hw.sdCard.path = C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/sdcard.img
>  disk.cachePartition = yes
>  disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/cache.img
>  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
>  hw.lcd.width = 480
>  hw.lcd.height = 800
>  hw.lcd.depth = 16
>  hw.lcd.density = 240
>  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
>  hw.gpu.enabled = no
>  hw.camera.back = none
>  hw.camera.front = none
>  vm.heapSize = 50
>  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
>  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
>  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
>  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
>  kernel.path = F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/system-images\android-10\x86\/kernel-qemu
>  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
>  disk.ramdisk.path = F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/system-images\android-10\x86\/ramdisk.img
 > disk.systemPartition.initPath = F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/system-images\android-10\x86\/system.img
>  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
>  disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userdata-qemu.img
>  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
>  avd.name = AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google
.
>QEMU options list:
>emulator: argv[00] = "F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk\tools\emulator-x86.exe"
>emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
>emulator: argv[02] = "C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk\tools\emulator-x86.exe -android-hw C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_
Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
>emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
>emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=F:\Tools\Programming\Android\ADT_Bundle\sdk/system-images\android
-10\x86\/system.img
>emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to C:\Users\KHOIV_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP9F58.tmp
>emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

>emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/userd
ata-qemu.img
>emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

>emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
>emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '50m'
>emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
>emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
>emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
>emulator: nand_add_dev: >cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\KhoiV_000\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google.avd/cache.im
g
>emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
```

> EMULATOR STOPPED WORKING ERROR DIALOG SHOW HERE....

Comment: Yeah! I fixed that. My problem is my GPU driver. My OS come with default GPU driver but It's not is my GPU manufactory. I remove it and update to latest version and my emulator work fine.

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly.