# Ubuntu crash when design Android layout by mouse

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, ubuntu, adt

I have a problem with android emulator here [My Android emulator cannot start. Error in load OpenGL lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606312/my-android-emulator-cannot-start-error-in-load-opengl-lib) but I have corrected it. But my Windows continuously crash BSOD critical structure corruption so I've moved to Ubuntu that I installed  with alongside Windows before. But this time I met a very confusing error. Every time I use the mouse to drag and drop the item in the preview panet to layout xml then Ubuntu automatic logout immediately. And that is android > 4.0 layout. Android 2.2 layout everything work fine.
And the GNOME image viewer of Ubuntu have same crash like that if I use mouse to scroll/drag my image.
I spent almost time to find out my problem on internet but no one have that problem like me. Please help me.

- My Ubuntu: 13.04 Raring 64bit
- JDK: 1.7.0.25 64 bit
- Android SDK: r22.01
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7600M