# My new Android virtual device is not working

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-virtual-device, eclipse-adt

I'm new to android software development. I downloaded adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702 , and also downloaded android system images for android 4.4W (API 20). when I created new android virtual devices I gave this error:

an android virtual devices that fail to load.

and when I start this virtual devices I gave this error:

Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/sosin/Desktop/ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

anyone can help me?

and when I tried to install these package I gave this error:

package are :

`lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libc6-i386`

error is:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:  lib32bz2-1.0 : PreDepends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.9-18) but it is not going to be installed  lib32ncurses5 : Depends: lib32tinfo5 (= 5.9-10) but it is not going to be installed                  Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed  lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: What is you Linux distribution? Does that path exists (`/home/sosin/Desktop/ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk//tools/emulator`)?

Comment: my Linux distribution is Debian 7.0 and yes that path exists.

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /path/to/emulator`?

Comment: output of ldd /home/sosin/Desktop/ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/emulator is: not a dynamic executable

Comment: There are two forward slashes on after `sdk` in your path. Could that perhaps be the issue?

Comment: @saman That's weird... Try to install those packages: `libc6:i386`, `libncurses5:i386` and `libstdc++6:i386`. Also check that those files have execution permission: `ls -la /home/sosin/Desktop/ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk//tools/*`.

Comment: I can't install libc6:i386. when I tried i gave this error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-i386: Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38+deb7u3) but 2.19-7 is to be installed
libc6-dev-i386: Depends: libc6-dev (= 2.13-38+deb7u3) but 2.19-7 is to be installed
Recommends: gcc-multilib but it is not going to be installed

Comment: @Salem and i haven't libncurses5:i386 and libstdc++6:i386 in my repository where can I find them?

Comment: @saman Run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and try again.

Comment: @Salem this link have same problem. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597781/an-android-virtual-device-that-failed-to-load?rq=1]. my problem is installing **libc6:i386**. I have been mention this in my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download less than version of your packages from packages.debian.org . Then install via `dpkg -i path/filename`.If you don't use dpkg with the command line, you use aptitude offers. It offers you downgrade your packages.

use aptitude such as :
`aptitude install libc6-i386 lib32z1`
after it use this command , try to install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`
or for earlier version use :
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using 64-bit Ubuntu, I also get this problem and 
refer to this
[the android emulator does not start, avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463197/the-android-emulator-does-not-start-avd?rq=1)

For latest Ubuntu you can install:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

For older versions, go for:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: when I tried that I gave this error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32bz2-1.0 : PreDepends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.9-18) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32ncurses5 : Depends: lib32tinfo5 (= 5.9-10) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: I think you should first update your repo,by sudo apt-get update and then try to install these packages

Comment: I do that but still have a problem

Comment: I used unstable package that it's version isn't suitable. I replace `libc6-i386` with lower version and used your command then virtual devises is run. please add this information to your answer and I will accept that for my question.